# Flask app with Flask-Limiter as a windows service using PyInstaller. Import error on limits

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a flask app that is working on a windows server as a service. I'm using win32service together with PyInstaller to create this service. It works without any problem, until I try to use the Flask-Limiter extension. It always crashes when starting the service on this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\**compiled code**\\server_service\\limits\\resources\\redis\\lua_scripts\\moving_window.lua'
```

It looks like the PyInstaller didn't include limits at all. I have tried to solve this by forcing PyInstaller to include it using the hidden imports flag, but this did not solve it

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import win32timezone --hidden-import Flask-Limiter --hidden-import limits -c server_service.py
```

Any idea what could be the problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

after trying many more options, I have found that adding  `--collect-all limits` to the PyInstaller call did solve this